# Node.Js Oracledb optional Array as IN bind parameter to Oracle Procedure

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to pass array in procedure as mentioned in following link but that array should be optional. I am doing bulk insert using forall in the procedure. but some time list can be empty as well and still other stuff in the procedure should be executed succesfully.

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#plsqlindexbybinds

```
connection.execute(
  "BEGIN mypkg.myinproc(:id, :vals); END;",
  [
    1234,
    { type: oracledb.NUMBER,
       dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
       val: [1, 2, 23, 4, 10]
    }
  ],

  function (err) { . . . });
```

works find but if i don't want to pass vals i am getting errors

i tried

```
val:[]
val: null
val: undefined

and not having val at all
```

i am getting following error messages

when trying to pass null or undefined or do not pass:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERT_PROCEDURE'
```

When trying to pass empty array

```
NJS-039: empty array is not allowed for IN bind
```

I did a work around by passing array with null

```
 val:[null]
```

and in procedure removing nulls from the list before executing FORALL.

this works for temporary but i would really like to solve this problem in proper way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to treat this as a bug (or design flaw) and get someone to look at it.
Both PHP OCI8 2.0 and Node node-oracledb 1.11 disallow binding empty arrays, but Python cx_Oracle doesn't.